# How to add all page specific entries from dependency

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I'm currently upgrading an existing app with legacy per-page frontend javascript and CSS to Symfony's Webpack Encore. The app and it's dependencies each supply their own [page-specific JavaScript or CSS](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#multiple-entries) in a `webpack.config.js`. For example:

**MyApp**

```
// webpack.config.js
  Encore
      // ...
      .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
      .addEntry('checkout', './assets/checkout.js')
      .addEntry('account', './assets/account.js')
      // ...
```

**TheDependencies**

```
// webpack.config.js
  Encore
      // ...
      .addEntry('login', './assets/login')
      .addEntry('logout', './assets/logout')
      // ...
```

Naturally the easy solution is to *manually* copy the dependencies entries into **MyApp** :

```
// webpack.config.js
  Encore
      // ...
      .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
      .addEntry('checkout', './assets/checkout.js')
      .addEntry('account', './assets/account.js')
      .addEntry('login', './node_modules/my-dependency/assets/login')
      .addEntry('logout', './node_modules/my-dependency/assets/logout')
      // ...
```

However, this pose problems (1) in the event the dependency is updated with new entries or (2) when multiple dependencies (~5) each supply multiple (10+) entries.

I want to find a way to easily import every page-specific entries from each dependencies. For example, something similar to this pseudo-code:

```
// webpack.config.js
  Encore
      // ...
      .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
      .addEntry('checkout', './assets/checkout.js')
      .addEntry('account', './assets/account.js')
      .addEntries('./node_modules/my-dependency/webpack.config.js')
      // ...
```

Is that possible and how could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I propose an answer that is not directly related to webpack. Even though you're maybe not using a JS framework, since 2015 (ES6), JavaScript has had the ES6 modules standard to import modules in Node.js, also supported by most browsers.

for example for your account (I assume it contains your login and logout in this example) and this is just a

Using package.json:

```
{
    "type": "module" }
```

With this, your source code should use import syntax

Then login.js (all your script here I put a function example) :

```
  export function login() {
      return "you're logged in";
    }
```

Then account.js

```
import { login } from './login.js';
let val = login();  val is "logged";
```

You can then just import your script account.js like you did in your webpack.
In the end, you can add few entries in your webpack config, depending on which scripts are loading in each script with the import call, but in a way it allows to organize them.

Comment: Not sure how `import` will solve "per page" scripts? Unless you're proposing webpack encore creates one entry for al script, and each page HTML import the necessary functions ?

Comment: Yes indeeed, if you're using Symfony, you can add one entry in your, maybe Twig template with the {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }} -> you can still use multiple entries, but you can organize them among webpack. Hope my answer is clear, wish you luck.